# increment all the rows of a column in 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode

I have a 2D array:

```
 A[65][4];
```

Is it possible to increment all the value of a specific column with looping through the row?

i.e. an equivalent command to:

```
 for (int i = 0 ; i < 65 ; i++)
      A[i][2]++;
```

Thanks

Comment: What you provided works fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Why not compile it, run it, and see?

Comment: I'm just curios to know

Comment: The best way to learn programming is by doing. Don't be afraid to make mistakes. Trial and error is great. Dig through the documentation.

Comment: "Is it possible to increment all the value of a specific column with looping through the row?

i.e. an equivalent command to:" Yeah, you even provided a valid subroutine.

Comment: The C++ language does not provide specific functions for processing matrices (2d arrays).  You  will have to write your own or search for a library.